# Need DOM selector for class and attribute

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

```
<div class="ag-header-cell ag-header-cell-sortable grid-column-header-forecast" col-id="AD" >

<div class="ag-header-cell ag-header-cell-sortable grid-column-header" col-id="AD" >
```

I have divs that are like above. Some have 'forecast' at end of class name, some don't.

I would like a document.querySelector that would yield col-id attribute of the first **forecast** div.

Comment: [Attribute selectors - Learn web development | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: DOM selectors select elements, not attributes. You can select the first div matching [a selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/) (you probably want a combination of a class selector and an attribute presence selector), then use `getAttribute` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @v.kostenko answer if you have a specific string name. 
But for more dynamic handling use this

```
document.querySelector('*[class$="forecast"]')
```

The above code will provide you with the first element details whose class contain `forecast` string, in the end, irrespective of any HTML element

Answer (score 1):

```
const forecast = document.querySelector('div.grid-column-header-forecast');
const colId = forecast.getAttribute('col-id');
```